# Number of events estimation

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation, distribution

[image]I have three different histograms (Impact parameter distributions) corresponding to three groups of the same particle with different properties. However, the three distribution have more or less the same shape. Now I want to predict a fourth distribution (with another property), which should have more or less the same shape as the three other ones. I have only a part of this latter distribution in a certain range.

A first attempt was to predict the rest of the distribution using a Transfer Factor (TF), which is the ratio of integrals in two different ranges, and by multiplying this TF to the integral of the known range in the fourth distribution, I could estimate the number of events in the unknown range. I did this using the three known distribution, but I obtained three different results, which were not even close to each other. I think that one of the three must be the good one, but I don't know which one.

My question: Is there a statistical method to determine the best one? or is there another way/method to approximate my last distribution?

Comment: Please add the histograms and distributions you refer to, it's very hard to understand what exactly is that you look for

Comment: I just added the histograms. So using these distributions, I want to predict a another one, because I believe that it will have a similar shape to one of these distributions (consider the green, blue and red one as one single distribution).

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you can the problem with polynomial regression. There is a single target "entries" and two features: 1: numeric "d0" and 2: categorical "Mu" type. Then try different polynomial orders to closely match the distributional shape.

After training the model, you'll predict the new data.

There are many ways to evaluate a model. The two common are:

1. Goodness of fit - How well does the model fit the training data?
2. Predictive - How well does the model predict novel data?